# Add custom route to viewsets.ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the docs there is the example of methods with custom url:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers

```
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @link(renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer])
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)
```

This example add following route:

```
url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/highlight/$', snippet_highlight, name='snippet-highlight'),
```

It is possible to add an url without pk param, like this?

```
r'^snippets/highlight/$'
```

Comment: Just create your own custom api view..

Comment: I just wanted to recommend [drf-extensions](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/), which provides `@link` and `@action`-decorators (and a extended router) that _can_ apply to the list-endpoint. 

But: 
you use `get_object` inside your method. Did you override it or how should get_object know which object to get if there is no pk in the url?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Just add your method in the viewset with the `list_route` decorator.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route  

class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @list_route(renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer])
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

It will add a url without the `pk` param like :

```
r'^snippets/highlight/$'
```

You can even specify the methods it supports using the `methods` argument in your decorator.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage

Comment: @list_route() is replaced with @action(detail=False) in recent versions, see @Roman's answer below

Answer (score 27):

The [ViewSets docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) mention using `action` decorator:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action


class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], name='Get Highlight')
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = models.Highlight.objects.all()

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then just update your queryset to do whatever it needs to do.

The advantage of doing it this way is that your serialisation is preserved.

If your `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from rest_framework import routers
from snippets import viewsets

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('snippets', viewsets.SnippetViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('snippets/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Then it is reachable via `http://localhost:8000/snippets/highlights`

To see usage for a `POST`, or how to change routing, see [docs for routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage).

Answer (score 12):

Since this question still turns up on first Google Page, here is up-to-date (for the late march of 2020) snippet (pun intended) to start working on your custom ModelViewSet route for single object:

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import action


class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'], name='Attach meta items ids')
    def custom_action(self, request, pk=None):
        """Does something on single item."""
        queryset = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Having default routers from the DRF tutorial will allow you to access this route with: `http://localhost:8000/snippets/<int:pk>/custom_action/`

Comment: How can I do the same, but get an object by unique field other than pk ('name')?

Comment: I mean to have it available at http://localhost:8000/snippets/name/<name>/

Comment: @CSZ Just set `detail=False`. Somehow, Django folks chose to have `detail` mean primary key. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯